# Should the response to HTTP OPTION request contain HSTS header?

Tags: http, https, hsts

According to the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security), HSTS header should be included in response to first https request. Does that mean response header for OPTION request should contain HSTS header as well?